# The most common and right pattern for performing synchronous tasks, asynchronous tasks to create a composite operation

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, asynchronous

I am rather new to iOS and Objective-C.

I am developing a project aiming to make a composition of complex (or "composite") operations as easy as possible: https://github.com/stanislaw/SACompositeOperations

I have four kinds of operations there: two single operations (sync and async) and two complex operations (cascaded and "transactional"). Single operations are used as "atoms" for complex operations, so I want to make them as good as possible in compliance with Objective-C best practices.

What I am interested in is: *what code should I choose for these single operations*?

By calling the first of two single operations "sync" I mean: run something probably asynchronous with completion handler and lock the flow waiting until it is done. "Async" means truly asynchronous operation - just run operation block in asynchronous fashion.

Here is the single operations code I currently use:

Sync operation

```
- (void)run:(syncOperationBlock)block {
    self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    block(self);

    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                                       beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
}

- (void)finish {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
}

@end
```

Async operation

```
- (void)run:(asyncOperationBlock)block {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("async_operation.queue", 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        block(self);
    });
}
```

I will be thankful, if someone can suggest any solutions for these single sync- and async- operations: *more generic*, *more common*, *just better* for the cases I've described

Shortly: what is the best code for forced-synchronous operation, for async operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project did evolve significantly since I've asked this question.

From the structural point of view, I can't say much interesting about asynchronous operations: in my project they are all based on dispatch_async and the most valuable functionality is implemented with intensive usage of blocks (mainly: yielding operations themselves to the blocks they execute, allows to control a flow of these operations).

The more interesting thing to note here is the code I currently use for synchronous (or "forced-synchronous") operations - though their usage should be avoided in real apps, they are still applicable in unit tests: one example is a need to straighten the curly asynchronous flow of asynchronous net request to test its result in place, in the context of unit test case.

Though I am posting this as an answer to my non-specific question I would still really like to see any authoritative answer about whether my SASyncOperation is good enough for forced-sync operations (in the sense I've described it in this question) or maybe it could be improved more.

[SASyncOperation](https://github.com/stanislaw/SACompositeOperations/blob/master/SACompositeOperations/SASyncOperation.m) as it currently written

- Does not block main thread if it is run on main thread.
- Does not produce excessive CPU polling as simple approaches with *while(!completed){};* do.

This is the most important part of the code:

```
#import "SASyncOperation.h"

@interface SASyncOperation () {
    BOOL _isOnMainThread;
    dispatch_semaphore_t _semaphore;
}
@end

@implementation SASyncOperation

// …

- (void)start {
    _semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    _operation(self);

    if (_finished) return;

    if ((_isOnMainThread = [NSThread isMainThread])) {
        while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
            CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, [[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceNow], NO);
        }
    } else {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }

    _finished = YES;
}

- (void)run:(^(void)(SASyncOperation *)block {
    _operation = [block copy];

    [self start];
}

- (void)finish {
    _finished = YES;

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);

    if (_isOnMainThread) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetMain());
        });
    }
}

// …
@end
```

This is how SASyncOperation should be used:

```
SASyncOperation *syncOperation = [[SASyncOperation alloc] init];

[syncOperation run:^(SASyncOperation *so) {
    doSomeThingMultiQueuedPossiblyMultiblockedAndAsynchronous(^{
        soOver = YES;
        [so finish];
    });
}]; // <- (*)

// (*) The flow will be stopped at this point waiting when 'so' operation will finish itself
```